# Mock random values into objects

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, easymock

I would like to avoid creating something like

```
User user = new User();
user.setValue1("val1");
user.setValue2("val2");

User savedUser = hibernate.save(user)

assertEquals(user.getVal1(), savedUser.getVal1);
assertTrue(savedUser.getVal3(), "somedata");
```

is there a way where I can use Mockito or something like that to mock random data into object?

Comment: Do you really have that many fields that this is cumbersome? You can always toy around with reflection but I don't particularly see a benefit unless you've got tens of fields.

Comment: well... I have around 15 probably, obviously it can be done, but I was expecting that something like Mockit.populateWithGibberish(User.class) can do it for me :) but I couldnt find anything like that

Comment: Don't mock values. Don't mock types you don't own. With hibernate or external framework write integration tests !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will return val1, val2, ... on each getXxx

```
    User user = mock(User.class, new Answer() {
        public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
            return invocation.getMethod().getName();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Won't this will result in assert failing everytime since getVal1 will result in different values on each invocation ?

Comment: I guess this will work only for String return methods but if I have a int/long/enum it will fail?

Comment: will fail for non-string types